# How can I solve Keyerror( return self.attrs[key]) to extract data on Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make web Scraper with Python and there is a problem in extracting title of company.

```
def extract_indeed_job():
jobs = []
result = requests.get(f"{url}&start={0*LIMIT}")
result_soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
results = result_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "tapItem"})
for result in results:
    title = result.find("h2", {"class": "jobTitle"}).find("span")["title"]
    company = result.find("span", {"class": "companyName"}).get_text()
    location = result.find("div", {"class": "companyLocation"}).get_text()
    print(title, company, location)
```

Some of posts, there are two span tags in the h2 class="jobTitle" tag  [image]

And I need to get just span title. So I wrote in with this tag. But, Python notices the key error and it doesn't work.

What can I do to solve? Is there any problem in my code??

Comment: find("span", title=True)['title']

Comment: Oh, So simple....... 
What makes the difference???
I mean, what is the function of 'title=True'?

Answer (score 0):

the `True` ensure that you are filtering those `span` with that attribute so when you try to access to its value you don't get an error. The `find` just returns a `span` careless of the attributes that you need.

```
result.find("span", title=True)['title']
```

The code and html you provided are ambiguos. Your statement `title = result.find("h2", {"class": "jobTitle"})` will never match the `h2` tag because its class attribute is more complex, ``jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob`. To match that you need

```
import re
...

result.find("h2", class_=re.compile(r'jobTitle'))
```

Use regular expression to improve the search in the soup.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are multiple `<span>`s inside `<h2>` element. You want `<span>` which is immediate child of `<h2>` rather than `<span>` inside `<div>`, to get it you might replace

```
result.find("h2", {"class": "jobTitle"}).find("span")
```

using

```
result.find("h2", {"class": "jobTitle"}).find("span", recursive=False)
```

This will prevent recursive search (i.e. looking for children of children and further)

Comment: getting confused... does a tag with "jobtTtle" exist? maybe `class_=re.compile(r'jobTtitle')`.  Make sense?